# How can I author a DAG which has a dynamic set of tasks relative to the execution date?

Tags: airflow

We have a DAG which pulls in some data from an ad platform. These ads are organized into campaigns. Our goal is to pull in the high-level metrics for these campaigns. To do so we first need to get the list of active campaigns for the given execution date--fortunately the ad platform's API makes this trivial, provided we know the time range we'd like to inquire about.

Currently our DAG is structured to go and fetch these campaigns and then to store them in S3 and finally Redshift. We then query Redshift before setting up the subsequent tasks which pull the data for each campaign. This is the gross part. We could also look in S3, but the trouble is the keys are templated with the value of the `ds` macro. There doesn't seem to be a way to know that value when constructing the DAG itself.

Our current approach also isn't aware of the execution date so it always queries all campaigns even if those campaigns aren't active for the time period we're interested in.

To make this a little more concrete, here's what that DAG looks like today:

[image: DAG of Ad Platform Campaign Metrics]

Another approach would be to roll this all up into a single operator that encapsulates getting the set of campaigns for the current execution date and then getting the metrics for each of those campaigns. We avoided this because that seems to preclude pulling the data in parallel via separate tasks per campaign.

How can we author this DAG such that we maintain the parallelization offered by dynamically querying the Redshift tables for campaigns but the campaigns are correctly constrained to the execution date?

Comment: Do I understand correctly that you have certain campaigns active for certain time periods and that you want your DAG tasks to be dynamically created if the time period is relevant?

Comment: @trejas that sounds like an accurate understanding, yes. For instance, I may run a campaign for June and in July end the campaign. At that point it's no longer active and won't show up in the ad platform's API response for future queries.

Comment: Do you know the length of each campaign in advance? And do the campaigns ever get extended or shortened?

Comment: Unfortunately we do not—campaigns are actually handled external to us and it would be very difficult to know without querying the ad platform’s API.

Comment: I'm trying to understand the problem, not very clear for me. Are you creating the parallel tasks dynamically so that each tasks fetches a single campaign data? And it is built based on the campaign meta data that was fetched before? I'm not sure how ds templating plays a role here, can you explain on that a bit? What is the actual problem, creating tasks which process campaigns which are no longer active?

Comment: I am trying to understand this. So in Redshift you have the active campaigns available. Your question is how to query the campaign data for active campaigns which are stored in Redshift? To break it into steps, can you query only the active campaigns from Redshift from your airflow task?

Comment: @bosnjak your question (or questions) are very hard to follow and unclear—I'm not sure what you’re confused about and what you’re asking.

Comment: @nightgaunt I’m really not sure what you’re asking.

Comment: @maxcountryman Can you explain what each task performs? Also in which task there is a dependency on ds macro?

Comment: @maxcountryman basically your question is unclear. you should try to explain in more details and precisely what is it you want to do.

Comment: @bosnjak How can we author this DAG such that we maintain the parallelization offered by dynamically querying the Redshift tables for campaigns but the campaigns are correctly constrained to the execution date?

Comment: @nightgaunt all tasks use the execution date in order to query the ad platform API by a given day. To understand how the tasks relate to each other, please re-read the question and refer to the screenshot which clearly illustrates the relationship you're asking about.

Comment: @maxcountryman So `extract-campaign` calls the API and stores the active campaign for the current execution_date in Redshift? `load-campaigns` fetches these campaigns from redshift again only based on exeution_date?  Then in each `extract-campaign-hourly-stats` task you ask more data for each campaign from API based on execution_date? And finally in `load-campaign-hourly-stats` you store the information in Redshift? I am really sorry but I am unable to understand what each task does.

Comment: Solution here will work for you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48197709/want-to-create-airflow-tasks-that-are-downstream-of-the-current-task

Comment: @JordanDuncan dynamically creating the tasks isn't really the issue, it's that there's no execution date when doing so. How does using the sub-dag operator change that? For example, how can you use the execution date when defining the tasks of a sub-dag?

Comment: @maxcountryman - i think the ds macro will help you with that: http://airflow.apache.org/macros.html - you can access ds or execution_date from all templates

Comment: @JordanDuncan can you illustrate what you're suggesting? I don't see where the ds macro or execution date are available to tasks being dynamically created, for a sub-dag or otherwise.

Comment: @maxcountryman It depends on what operator you are using to run your tasks. The most common way is through PythonOperator where provide_context=True, like:

t1 = PythonOperator(
  dag=dag,
  task_id='task_1',
  provide_context=True,
  python_callable=myPythonFunc,
)

def myPythonFunc(**context):
  ds = context['ds']

Comment: @JordanDuncan right but the point is to construct the operators based on the value of execution date--I still don't see how this helps. In the original post I mention that we could do this all in a single operator, but that that precludes natural parallelism.

Comment: @maxcountryman see #8 on this page: https://medium.com/datareply/airflow-lesser-known-tips-tricks-and-best-practises-cf4d4a90f8f

as well as this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50354818/how-to-really-create-n-tasks-in-a-subdag-based-on-the-result-of-a-previous-task

First step is to get list of campaigns you want to etl.  Then dynamically create the subdags.  I think these links will give you all the info you need to put it together!

Comment: @JordanDuncan you're skipping over the most important part: getting the campaigns you want to ETL--these have to be bounded by execution date. The sub-dags are unnecessary, you can just create a dynamic set of tasks for processing the campaigns once you have them. But the issue is how do you select only the campaigns for a given execution date such that you can build the dynamic set of tasks that processes them? Unfortunately the sub-dag operator doesn't help with that since it doesn't expose the context (of the parent dag) or more specifically the execution date.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe this is possible. The DAG can only render in one configuration defined by the DAG's python definition. You won't be able to control which version of the DAG renders as a function of execution date, so you won't be able to look back at how a DAG should render in the past, for instance. If you want the current DAG to render based on execution date then you can possibly write some logic in your DAG's python definition.

Depending on how you orchestrate your Airflow jobs, you may be able to have a single operator as you described, but have that single operator then kick off parallel queries on Redshift and terminate when all queries are complete.

Comment: "If you want the current DAG to render based on execution date then you can possibly write some logic in your DAG's python definition."

If that's possible, why wouldn't that be possible for any arbitrary execution date?

Comment: Absolutely possibly. Just going to require some specific abstraction. Will write an answer sometime later today.

Comment: @maxcountryman You'll be able to render the current and only DAG shape, but not be able to retrospect on what the DAG shape was in the past and therefore not be able to for any arbitrary execution date. but it looks like I may have possibly misunderstood the question, so I'll look forward to trejas' answer.

Comment: @trejas I added a 100 point bounty in case you’re still interested in taking a crack at this.

Comment: Sure. I’ll take a shot at it during lunch. Just to make sure, creating this will require you to store some of the data/inputs for dag configuration in a database. Also, this will require dynamic dag creation.

Comment: @trejas right, some of the state is necessarily encoded in the database (even now that's the case with the campaign IDs). I suspect there's some way of achieving this with a dynamic DAG.

Answer (score 0):

A caveat, in the interest of time I am going to piece together ideas and code examples from third party sources. I will give credit to those sources so you can take a look at context and documentation. An additional caveat, I have not been able to test this, but I am 99% certain this will work.

The tricky part of this whole operation will be figuring out how to handle your campaigns that might have ended and have started back up. Airflow is not going to like a DAG with a moving start or stop date. Moving the stop date might work a little better, moving the start date for the dag does not work at all. That said, if there are campaigns that get extended you should be able to move the end date as long as there are no gaps in continuity. If you have a campaign that lapses and then gets extended with a couple of non-active days in between you will probably want to figure out how to make those two look like unique campaigns to airflow.

## First step

You will want to create a python script that will call your database and return the relevant details from your campaigns. Assuming it is in MySQL it will look something like this, an example connection from [PyMySQL pip package documentation](https://pymysql.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/examples.html):

```
import pymysql.cursors

# Connect to the database
connection = pymysql.connect(host='localhost',
                             user='user',
                             password='passwd',
                             db='db',
                             charset='utf8mb4',
                             cursorclass=pymysql.cursors.DictCursor)

try:
    with connection.cursor() as cursor:
        # Create a new record
        sql = "INSERT INTO `users` (`email`, `password`) VALUES (%s, %s)"
        cursor.execute(sql, ('webmaster@python.org', 'very-secret'))

    # connection is not autocommit by default. So you must commit to save
    # your changes.
    connection.commit()

    with connection.cursor() as cursor:
        # Read a single record
        sql = "SELECT `id`, `password` FROM `users` WHERE `email`=%s"
        cursor.execute(sql, ('webmaster@python.org',))
        result = cursor.fetchall()
finally:
    connection.close()
```

## Second step

You will want to iterate through that cursor and create your dags dynamically similar to this example from [Astronomer.io](https://www.astronomer.io/guides/dynamically-generating-dags/):

```
from datetime import datetime

from airflow import DAG

from airflow.operators.python_operator import PythonOperator


def create_dag(dag_id,
               schedule,
               dag_number,
               default_args):

    def hello_world_py(*args):
        print('Hello World')
        print('This is DAG: {}'.format(str(dag_number)))

    dag = DAG(dag_id,
              schedule_interval=schedule,
              default_args=default_args)

    with dag:
        t1 = PythonOperator(
            task_id='hello_world',
            python_callable=hello_world_py,
            dag_number=dag_number)

    return dag


# build a dag for each number in range(10)
for campaign in result:  # This is the pymysql result from above
    dag_id = 'hello_world_{}'.format(str(n))

    default_args = {'owner': 'airflow',
                    'start_date': datetime(2018, 1, 1)
                    }

    schedule = '@daily'

    dag_number = n

    globals()[dag_id] = create_dag(dag_id,
                                  schedule,
                                  dag_number,
                                  default_args)
```

If you house all of this code in a single file, it will need to go in your ***dags*** folder. When a new campaign shows up in your database you will create a dag from it and can use your subdag architecture to run exactly the same set of steps/tasks with parameters pulled from that MySQL database. To be safe, and keep recent campaigns in your dag list I would write the mysql query with a date buffer. This way you still have dags that have ended recently in your list. The day these dags end you should populate the `end_date` argument of the dag.

Comment: Let me know if this explanation gives you enough of an idea of how to put it together. It looks to me like you have enough knowledge of subdags to get it working.

Comment: I think this makes sense, basically you're suggesting we separately query the ad platform API for the current set of active campaigns (this could be based on execution date if we assume there's a separate DAG handling that), persist those records in our database, then use those database records to construct a dynamic DAG? This doesn't give up on the parallelism (because we're creating a DAG per campaign) and allows us to constraint the query for the campaigns by the execution date, I believe. I think this will be an improvement over what we're doing if I'm following correctly.

Comment: I guess my only remaining question is can we constrain the set of campaigns we actually use to build the dynamic DAG by execution date? For example, what if I want to backfill data from last week: I query the ad platform API with last week's execution date, it shows me a (different) set of campaigns, I can store that in the db with the timestamp it was active for. But then how does the database query become constrained by last week's execution date?

Comment: You’re following my suggestion correctly. Although I would not constrain the query to create the dags entirely to the execution_date. You might want a day or two buffer to allow for closing out the campaigns in your database to follow through properly in Airflow. Otherwise you could encounter a situation where the campaign has been “closed” in the database but airflow doesn’t see that campaign when it makes it daily request.

Comment: I think because we run this DAG hourly, that kind of buffer won't be necessary--or at most would be +1 hour. We'd still want to constrain the campaigns because if we don't we'd end up querying for campaigns that don't exist (in the case of a backfill that happened for a date before a campaign was created) or including campaigns that have ended (in the case of future runs). Essentially we need some way to reliably backfill arbitrary dates and the execution date seems the most logical constraint.

Comment: No problem. Let me know how this goes. Interested to see, we have been thinking about setting up something similar. Different industry and slightly different use case. But I would definitely like to know how well it works.

Comment: I think the issue for us is still figuring out how we can constrain the campaigns by execution date.

Comment: Curious if you are going to accept this answer. I am about to create something similar and am certain this will work.

Comment: unfortunately we still haven't figured out how to constrain the campaigns by execution date.

Comment: Understand I did not solve your issue but this method will work. I implemented it in our environment works like a champ.